# Python - Parse a string with custom price units

Tags: python, string, parsing

What is fastest way to parse a string to int in Python? The string may include custom units, such as "k" (kilo), "m" (million), or "b" (billion).

For example:

```
100  -> 100
100k -> 100000
100m -> 100000000
100b -> 100000000000
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def convert(val):
    lookup = {'k': 1000, 'm': 1000000, 'b': 1000000000}
    unit = val[-1]
    try:
        number = int(val[:-1])
    except ValueError:
        # do something
    if unit in lookup:
        return lookup[unit] * number
    return int(val)

>>> print convert("100m")
>>> 100000000
```

Create a lookup table and then split the number into the number portion and the unit. If the unit portion exists, look to our table and use it to create the final number. Otherwise, return the number.

Answer (score 2):

```
def numerize(s):
    multipliers = {'k': 10**3, 'm': 10**6, 'b': 10**9}

    if s[-1] in multipliers:
        return int(s[:-1]) * multipliers[s[-1]]
    else:
        return int(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: better exemplification, possible-error fix

```
>>> def get_unit(ustr):
...     if ustr == '': return 'u'
...     return ustr.lower()
... 
>>> import re
>>> r=re.compile('([1-9][0-9]*)([kKmMbBgG]?)')

>>> units={'k':1000,'m':1000000,'g':1000000000,'b':1000000000,'u':1}
>>> result=r.match('120k')
>>> int(result.group(1))*units[get_unit(result.group(2))]
120000
>>> result=r.match('44')
>>> int(result.group(1))*units[get_unit(result.group(2))]
44
>>> result=r.match('44M')
>>> int(result.group(1))*units[get_unit(result.group(2))]
44000000
>>>
```

Comment: we could just use `units[result.group(2)]` and have `'':1` in units.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dictionary that maps numbers to themselves and units to zeros:

```
units = {"0":"0", "1":"1", #etc.
         "k":"000",
         "m":"000000"} # etc.
```

Then you convert a string to an int like this

```
int_value = int("".join(map(units.get, string_value)))
```

Comment: @Kimvais: What do you mean? What should I `str`?

Comment: This solution is really not ideal. While a nice idea, it doesn't cater for situations where the multiplier doesn't end in X amount of zeros, e.g. when you want K to be *1024.